# What's the best way to imitate the harp's bisbigliando effect on a piano?

Tags: piano, composition, transcription, harp

If I want to transcribe/arrange a harp piece for the piano, and the piece contains lots of [bisbigliando](http://sites.siba.fi/web/harpnotation/manual/plucked-sounds/bisbigliando) passages, what would be the best way to imitate that charming effect on the piano, and how would I notate it as clearly as possible?

Comment: Well, I learned a new word today!

Comment: Could you please post an image with the bisbigliando  you'd like to transcribe to piano.

Comment: An image would be very helpful. Have you by any chance got the sheet music of  Debussy's Preludes? If any piano-writing produces that effect it's there. I could give you bar references.

Comment: Looks like the best you can do is mark a trill as pianissimo, and maybe even notate "fastest trill possible"

Answer (score 1):

The *best* way would be, well, take a grab in the piano and play an actual bisbigliando on the strings! But that's hardly practical.

Short of that, I don't think there's much better you can do than using both the sustain and *una corda* pedals and then using a regular pianissimo trill.

If you have the option to prepare the piano, or use a digital one, there are a couple of options that could get you closer. Soft cotton wool on the hammers and/or strings, echo devices for a denser sound, or detuning the next key down a semitone so you can use two keys for the same note (again facilitating denser tremolo) might be things to consider.

Comment: "well, take a grab in the piano and play", well, it has [been done](https://youtu.be/0ra6B5evR2o?t=1081) (and using a pickup moments after). That said, not sure it is practical, as you said ;) …